# HQL impossible to read attribute which is an instance of subclass

Tags: hibernate, inheritance, polymorphism, hql, subclass

First, i want to say that I have read dozens of articles about inheritance mapping or polymorphic fetch with hibernate without finding solution to my problem.
Though the case is very simple.

When executing the code below:
        List meals = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                .createQuery("select m from Meal m").list();
I get the error below:
org.hibernate.WrongClassException: Object with id: 1 was not of the specified subclass: com.myPack.Fruit (Discriminator: Orange)

Actually, I can't read the abstract class fruit which is subclassed in Orange or Apple

A Meal contains of Fruit which can be Orange or Apple

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@Table(name = "fruit")
public abstract class Fruit {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true)
    private Integer id;
}

@Entity(name = "Orange") //this is the discriminatorValue stored in dtype column
public class Orange extends Fruit {
}

@Entity(name = "Apple") //this is the discriminatorValue stored in dtype column
public class Orange extends Fruit {
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "meal")
public class Meal {
    ...

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fruit_id", nullable = false)
    private Fruit fruit  = null;
}
```

The fetch is not LAZY so I shouldn't have any problem with the proxy.
I  don't understand why hibernate is not able to find out that such Fruit is an Orange or Apple as the Fruit table contains in DTYPE column the discriminator Orange or Apple

I would be very grateful to solve this problem.
(sorry for my vague english)

.
.

After further research I found that @DiscriminatorOptions(force = true) could solve my trouble but finally...helplessly.
What I have learned is that even if hibernate has all the information to find what is concrete class, annotation like @DiscriminatorOptions(force = true) are needed in some cases.
Anyway, i would like to tell hibernate : "hey hibernate don't try to instanciate  abstract Fruit class, because it is abstract. hey hibernate try rely on entity with @DiscriminatorValue set on" .. but hibernate is deaf :(

Answer (score 0):

Replace this and try

```
List meals = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Meal").list();
```

Comment: changing fom createQuery("select m from Meal m") to createQuery("from Meal") has no effect in 4.1.0.Final hibernate version.
But moving to 4.2.4 or 4.3.4 version the behavior is different but in both cases the issue remains:

Comment: createQuery("from Meal") implies the exception
createQuery("select m from Meal m") implie no exception but the attribute fruit of Meal is null.
After all, it is functionally the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've been experiencing the exact same problem using Spring 4.0.2 and Hibernate 4.3.4.  I think there is something missing from the dependencies of my project or possibly just a bug in Hibernate.

I would suggest you roll back your Hibernate version, the last working version I had was 4.2.4 which I'm in the process of reverting to.

Comment: changing fom 4.1.0.Final hibernate version to 4.2.4 or 4.3.4 version the behavior is different but in both cases the issue remains:
in 4.1.0.Final createQuery("select m from Meal m") implies the exception
in 4.2.4 or 4.3.4 createQuery("select m from Meal m") implie no exception but the attribute fruit of Meal is null.
After all, it is functionally the same problem.